# Site icon disappears

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app, android-app-feed

It seems that on the feed in the Android app if two or more feed items are from the same site then only the first item will show the site icon.

[image]

Comment: That happens in the iOS app too and I believe it's by-design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design, the items that belong to the same site are in the same grouping, that's why they also don't have a big horizontal line between them, like the second item in your screenshot and the row of hot questions do.